# MongoDB: Schema hasn't been registered for model "User"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have been trying to add authentication feature to my angular app using express and mongo and I am getting the following error on line **app.js 9:1**:

```
"Schema hasn't been registered for model "User"" 
'Use mongoose.model(name, schema)', 
name: 'MissingSchemaError'
```

Following is my **app.js**:

```
require('dotenv').config();
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var passport = require('passport');
require('./app_server/models/db');
require('./app_server/config/passport');  ----> This line is the one thats throwing the error


var indexRouter = require('./app_server/routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./app_server/routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app_server','views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

Following is my **passport.js**:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStratergy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('User');  ---> Probably the culprit

passport.use(new LocalStratergy({usernameField: 'email'},
    function(username, password, done){
        User.findOne({email: username}, function(err, user){
            if (err) { return done(err); }

            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'Incorrect Email.'
                });
            }

            if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'Incorrect Password.'
                });
            }
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));
```

Following is my **users.js**:

```
var mongoose = require('Mongoose');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    fullname: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    hash: String,
    salt: String
});
```

Following is my **db.js:**

```
var mongoose = require('Mongoose');

var dbURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/buddhafinds";
mongoose.connect(dbURI);

//Related functions and logs go here

require('./users');
```

I have been struggling with this since morning. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your passport.js file you create a model without a schema

```
var User = mongoose.model('User');
```

try to assign the model to schema in your users.js file and export it from there

```
exports.User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

then just require User in any file you want